# Python FTP uploading bar

Tags: python, file-upload, ftp

I am uploading a file with FTPLib in python and have a cli loadingbar with [progressbar 2.2.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2) 
I need to make a loading bar to tell the progress of the upload.

Does anyone have any info on the topic?

Thanks, giodamelio

---

As Senthil Kumaran pointed out, there is a callback parameter in the ftplib.storbinary function but I do not know how to use it.

I tried this. I expected it to print the message every time a byte was uploaded.

```
import ftplib

def callback():
    print("This is the callback function")

s = ftplib.FTP('myserver.com','login','password') # Connect

f = open('test.txt','rb')                # file to send
s.storbinary('STOR test.txt', f, 1024, callback())         # Send the file

f.close()                                # Close file and FTP
s.quit()
```

Comment: Don't call your callback - you're actually passing None in as the callback here.

Comment: I have never used a callback function before so I'm a little confused. Which part should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small change to your code:

```
import ftplib

def callback(p):
    print("This is the callback function")

s = ftplib.FTP('myserver.com','login','password') # Connect

f = open('test.txt','rb')                # file to send
s.storbinary('STOR test.txt', f, 1024, callback)         # Send the file

f.close()                                # Close file and FTP
s.quit()
```

The callback needs to be called later on. If you invoke it as you pass it as a parameter, it's return value is passed instead. Since your `callback` function has no return, it would pass in `None`.

Comment: On a side note, the `ftplib.storbinary` function passes each block of data back to the call back function so it had to be `def callback(param1):`

Answer (score 2):

A specific question like showing a code sample of what you tried would helpful to answer.
The showing of progress using an indicator is possible when the FTP library provides certain facilities of `callback` functions and you use your progress indicator function (which in this case is progressbar) and attach it to that callback. Looking at the [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) documentation, there are provisions to attach callbacks to certain methods, perhaps that should be useful for you.

Comment: darn... must be tired. I looked there for a callback function and somehow missed it. Will give updated code in morning.